# How to code a through-beam sensor to detect LED using a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, gpio

I am using a Raspberry Pi to connect a through beam sensor (model: EE-SPWL311) for my own project. The sensor is to be connected onto the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi. I would like to know how to code, using python whenever the sensor is detected, a led will light up and whenever it is not detected, the led would not light up.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)  /* For the Through-Beam Sensor */
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT) /* For the LED */
```

(Help Me To Continue)

Comment: If these methods are onClick callbacks, shouldn't you just disable button itself?

Comment: I know i can disable the button. But i want to do it another way

Comment: @destinystazz, Please don't vandalise your old questions. Just use the "Ask Question" button and create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way is to use a polling loop

```
while True:
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.input(23))
```

When you decide you want some CPU for other things, try something like this

```
while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.RISING)
    GPIO.output(26, True)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
    GPIO.output(26, False)
```

You can swap the `True`/`False` around if the led lights up the wrong way round

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see anything in this post regarding `GPIO` or Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @JoelCornett, the OP vandalised the question